# I need to find the largest number in a partially filled array

Tags: c++, arrays

So I have a partially filled array and I'm trying to find the biggest number. All of the tools my teacher gave us only works with completely filled arrays, so I'm lost here.

My arrays are parallel. One is a double array (but keeps outputting int when being viewed - I'll ask about that later) and the other is a string.

We have to display the information in console art. That's why I have to find the biggest, so we can generate a screen that wont be too big or too small. The largest number will be the one with the biggest art of course, and the rest of them are going to be calculated based on percentages of the big one.

Here's my function:

```
int findLargest(double sales[])
{
    int indexOfLargest = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        if (sales[i] > sales[indexOfLargest])
        indexOfLargest = i;
    }
    return indexOfLargest;
}
```

Here's what part of main looks like:

```
double sales[100];
string names[100];

int elementNumber = 0;

elementNumber = findLargest(sales);
cout << "largest element number is " << elementNumber << endl;
```

When I run this code to test it, it outputs that the array with the largest number has the index of 78, even though I have one entry so it should be 0. Terribly confused honestly, any COMPREHENSIVE resources would be great.

EDIT: This is being saved into a text file and must be reused.

YET ANOTHER EDIT:
Now I can get a size for the array! Yipee! But all of your suggestions to find the biggest one (by using a size) are not working for me.

Here's my current code snippet from main

```
string fileName = "";
int size = 0;
int indexOfLargest = 0;
indexOfLargest = findLargest(sales, size, fileName);
```

Here's the function:

```
int findLargest(double sales[], int &sz, string fileName) 
{
    double numbers = 0;
    string names;
    int indexOfLargest = 0;
    ifstream fin(fileName.c_str());
    if (fin)
    {
        cout << "file opened" << endl;
        while (isalnum(fin.peek()))
        {
            getline(fin, names);
            fin >> numbers;
            fin.ignore(5, '\n');
            sz++;
        }
        cout << "The size is " << sz << endl;
        //size = 4
        if (sz == 0) return -1;  // no data means no highest index
        for (int i = 0; i < sz; ++i)
        {
            if (sales[i] > sales[indexOfLargest])
                indexOfLargest = i;
        }
        cout << "Index: " << indexOfLargest;
        fin.close();
     }

    return indexOfLargest;
```

Again, thank you for putting time into this. My partner and I were so confused. It blows my mind that some people got this done in the two hours given.

Comment: What do you mean, specifically, by "partially filled array"? Arrays in C++ do not have the concept of partially or completely filled. There is always data in every element, although it might not be what you expect.

Comment: Really? My teacher explained us the concept of partially-filled (no wonder I'm having a heck of time trying to find info this then) In the program, the user can enter a name and a number and that gets saved to an array. I made an array with a size of 100, even though I don't expect 100. It's getting so complicated to me and my teacher didn't do a very good job of explaining it.

Comment: Complaining about "partially filled array" terminology is pedantic and unhelpful; sometimes array elements aren't initialised (and reading from them would have undefined behaviour), while other times they're not populated with "meaningful" data from the perspective of the application. The important point is that the compiler/language doesn't track how much of the array's "filled", so *you* need to e.g. keep your own counter or ensure there's a "sentinel" value (a value your actual data would never contain) in the first element that's not part of your logical data set.

Comment: You discard values read from file. I think you mean `fin >> sales[sz];`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays have a size, and *all* elements exist within the array. There are no partially filled arrays unless you impose your *own* limitations (and code) upon them.

So, if by partially filled, you simply mean you're only using (for example) the first ten of those one hundred array elements, you simply have to limit your checks to that area, with something like:

```
int findLargest(double sales[], int sz) {
    if (sz == 0) return -1;  // no data means no highest index
    int indexOfLargest = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < sz; i++)
        if (sales[i] > sales[indexOfLargest])
            indexOfLargest = i;
    return indexOfLargest;
}
```

That, of course, means you need to maintain the size along with the arrray:

```
double sales[100];
int sz = 0;
sales[sz++] = 3.141592653589;
sales[sz++] = 2.718281828459;
int highIdx = findLargest (sales, sz);
```

For example, here's a test program which uses a large array `buff` and imposes *extra* information `sz` on that array:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    char buff[1000];
    int sz = 0;
    buff[sz++] = '3'; buff[sz++] = '.'; buff[sz++] = '1';
    buff[sz++] = '4'; buff[sz++] = '1'; buff[sz++] = '5';

    printf ("Buffer size is %d\n", sizeof (buff));
    printf ("Buffer used is %d\n", sz);
    printf ("Buffer is ");
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
        putchar (buff[i]);
    putchar ('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
Buffer size is 1000
Buffer used is 6
Buffer is 3.1415
```

Perhaps a more applicable piece of code would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int findLargest(double sales[], int sz) {
    if (sz == 0) return -1;
    int indexOfLargest = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < sz; i++)
        if (sales[i] > sales[indexOfLargest])
            indexOfLargest = i;
    return indexOfLargest;
}

#define SZ 15

int main (void) {
    double sales[SZ];
    int sz = 0;

    srand (time (NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < SZ; i++)
        sales[i] = 9999.99;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        sales[sz++] = (float)(rand() % 10000) / 100;

    printf ("Array size is: %d\n", sizeof (sales) / sizeof (*sales));
    printf ("Array used is: %d\n", sz);
    printf ("Array is:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < SZ; i++)
        printf ("   %2d: %8.2f%s\n", i, sales[i], (i < sz) ? "" : " - unused");
    printf ("Highest value at index: %d\n", findLargest (sales, sz));

    return 0;
}
```

which, for a couple of test runs, shows you the function in action:

```
Array size is: 15
Array used is: 10
Array is:
    0:    22.66
    1:    10.66
    2:    63.28
    3:    41.05
    4:    22.50
    5:    78.05
    6:    56.96
    7:    21.48
    8:    21.69
    9:    98.77
   10:  9999.99 - unused
   11:  9999.99 - unused
   12:  9999.99 - unused
   13:  9999.99 - unused
   14:  9999.99 - unused
Highest value at index: 9
```

(seeing that index 9 is the highest value `98.77`), and

```
Array size is: 15
Array used is: 10
Array is:
    0:    93.56
    1:    94.28
    2:    38.54
    3:    36.54
    4:    20.90
    5:    38.39
    6:    15.02
    7:     5.18
    8:    67.72
    9:    17.09
   10:  9999.99 - unused
   11:  9999.99 - unused
   12:  9999.99 - unused
   13:  9999.99 - unused
   14:  9999.99 - unused
Highest value at index: 1
```

(with index 1 is the highest value `94.28`).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I want to try that, but how can I find the size of the current number of elements that get filled though?

Comment: @Hannah, you have to maintain it somewhere yourself or use a different collection that does know the size. Arrays on their own have no concept of used/unused, only of size and values.

Comment: Can you direct me to any references to understand this better?

Comment: @Hannah, I've added a complete sample which should (hopefully) be clearer.

Comment: Very helpful so far!! I have been able to create a size counter within the function. But when I tried that for loop at the top of your answer, it is returning 0.

Comment: Which isn't the index with the highest number, I should add

Comment: @Hannah, suggest you look at my updated code, it shows how to use the function in detail.

Comment: I've fixed this problem using your answer and now I am trying to accomplish another task within my code. Could you check out my other question? Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a `vector` instead of an `array`. Whenever you need to add an element, use the `push_back` method to append it to the vector. Then, you can rewrite the `findLargest` function as follows:

```
int findLargest(vector<double>& sales)
{
    int indexOfLargest = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < sales.size(); i++)
    {
        if (sales[i] > sales[indexOfLargest])
        indexOfLargest = i;
    }

    return indexOfLargest;
}
```

**EDIT:** From what I understand, the main difficulty you're facing is that you dont know what the size of the array would be and hence, you end up allocating extra space. As mentioned above, using a vector would help you overcome this problem. It'll dynamically resize as you push elements into it. And you won't have to worry about keeping track of the actual size of the array.

Comment: I should have mentioned that this is a school assignment and we have to use arrays. Dang it!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get away with passing the size of the array in:

```
int GetLargestElementByIndex(double sales[], size_t size)
{
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        if (sales[i] > sales[index])
            index = i;
    }
    return index;
}
```

Which would be called like so:

```
double sales[8] = { 5.5, 2.2, 1.8, 6.6, 9.3, 14.0, 3.5, 9.2 };
int largestIndex = GetLargestElementByIndex(sales, 8);
```

However, you could also do it using templates:

```
// Because we are using a template, this can be used with any array that has operator > declared for it, rather than restricting its use for an int or double
// Type = the type of the object (e.g. int, double, std::string). This is implicitly deduced from the array passed in
// size = this is the size of the array implicitly determined by the array passed in
template <typename Type, size_t size>
int GetLargestElementByIndex(const Type (&arrayOfType)[size]) // pass a const reference as we do not need to modify this object
{
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        if (arrayOfType[i] > arrayOfType[index])
            index = i;
    }
    return index;
}
```

This is called like the above, but without the need to pass in the size, and it works with more types than just doubles:

```
double sales[] = { 2.2, 3.3, 1.0, -1.5, 5.9, 6 };
int largestIndex = GetLargestElementByIndex(sales);
int wholeSales[] = { 19, 33, 1, -4, -100, 60 };
largestIndex = GetLargestElementByIndex(wholeSales);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is to keep track of the largest values as you input them:

```
double sales[100];
string names[100];
int num_entries = 0;
size_t max_sales_index = 0;
while (num_entries < sizeof(sales) / sizeof(sales[0]) &&
       std::cin >> sales[num_entries] &&
       getline(std::cin, names[num_entries]))
{
    if (sales[num_entries] > sales[max_sales_index])
        max_sales_index = num_entries;
    ++num_entries;
}
cout << "largest element number is " << max_sales_index << endl;
```

This code tracks the number of entered elements in `num_entries`.  With that number, you could call a "find-largest" function, but why bother?